# My program freezes as soon as I click the "Calculate" button Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following program. I have figured out the way I want the numbers calculated. I am struggling with the interface. I want something super basic and simple but it seems to freeze every time I click the "Calculate" button. Anyone can give me some advice/help?

```
import random
from tkinter import *

def Calculate():

    revenue = revenue_field.get()

    total_hrs = int(revenue)/17.5
    total_hrs = round(total_hrs)

    monThur, friSun = 0, 0

    while (monThur*15 + friSun*20) != int(revenue) or monThur > 960 or friSun > 792:
        monThur = random.randint(0, total_hrs+1)
        friSun = total_hrs - monThur

    result = "You need to have " + str(monThur) + " hours sold between Monday and Thursday and " + str(friSun) + " hours sold between Friday and Sunday to achieve a revenue of " + str(revenue)

    result_field.insert(END, result + '\n')


gui = Tk()


gui.configure(background="light green")

gui.title("Reverse Revenue")

gui.geometry("270x150")

revenue = IntVar()
revenue_field = Entry(gui)
revenue_field.grid(columnspan=4, ipadx=70)


button1 = Button(gui, text=' Calculate ', fg='black', bg='red', command=Calculate, height=1, width=7)
button1.grid(row=2, column=2)

result_field = Text(gui)


gui.mainloop()
```

EDIT: I have fixed the freezing but now when I click Calculate, nothing happens, no ouput, nothing.

Comment: That `while` loop probably never ends. Maybe the `!= revenue` bit should be `< revenue`?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AKX , I did try with an input where the while loop ends

PranavHosangadi excuse me, I will take the tour.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I have tried debugging, nothing shows up, the gui just freezes and nothing happens, can't see any thing in the debugger..

Comment: The only explanation is that your `while` loop never terminates. Without question that's the problem.

Comment: add stdout statements after each line. for your use case add print ('Inside while loop') will help

Comment: In short, this logic is freezing your screen: (monThur*15 + friSun*20) != int(revenue). Apart from this there are many other logic flaws. You'll need to learn how to translate your logic into code.

Answer (score 1):

I added result_field.grid() after the line where I create the result_field and Voila, getting the result now.